# When using Pyinstaller 2.0 syntax error in pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/util.py

Tags: python, executable, exe, python-2.5, pyinstaller

I have just installed PyInstaller 2.0 and I have been attempting to use it to create an executable of a python script. However, from terminal, when I cd into the directory pyinstaller-2.0 and run the command directed in the included `README` text file as follows:

`python pyinstaller.py Path/to/my/application.py`

I receive an error message, that seems to indicate a syntax error in one of the PyInstaller files:

```
File "pyinstaller.py", line 26, in <module>
    import PyInstaller.build
  File "/Desktop/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/build.py", line 30, in <module>
    import bindepend
  File "/Desktop/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/bindepend.py", line 30, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.depend import dylib
  File "/Desktop/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/depend/dylib.py", line 149, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.lib.macholib import util
  File "/Desktop/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/util.py", line 136
    except (IOError, os.error) as why:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a step I am missing? Is this a common error? I am using Python 2.5.1 on Mac OSX 10.5.8.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.5 does not use the `except Exception as name:` format. Use  `except Exception, name:` instead.

For more information see http://docs.python.org/2.5/tut/node10.html

Comment: so PyInstaller 2.0 is not compatible with Python 2.5? That seems strange, since the website states it works with any version of Python since 2.3 -http://www.pyinstaller.org/report/1?sort=milestone&asc=0&page=2

Comment: On their website they claim _Multiversion: works under any version of Python from 2.3 up to 2.7._ so it's possible that something else is not correct. By the way, are you trying to run the Pyinstaller module along with your application? The correct syntax is `python -m pyinstaller.py Path/to/my/application.py` if you are.

Comment: Right, sorry, but 2.5.1 would fall in that category. And I am not sure, is the command to generate the executable from the command prompt the module? when I run the command as you have above:
`python -m PyInstaller  Path/to/application.py`
It seems to complete successfully, but does not generate the executable.

Comment: It's possible you might need to pass it an argument for where to put the executable. `-o /path/file` is generally the argument used to specify an outfile location. If that doesn't work you might try `-h` to print the help message.

Comment: Ah. When I try either of those additional arguments it the command completes the associated directories(dist..etc) as well as the executable are not generated. I am confused, because the manual included says to run:
`python pyinstaller.py [opts] yourprogram.py`
from the directory the pyinstaller directory, which, generates the invalid syntax error seen above. The -h argument does not seem to function when using module syntax.

Comment: BTW, according to the [Pyinstaller documentation](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#allowed-options) if you want a single file you need to use the `--onefile` option. To be quite honest I'm not sure what the problem is... I don't use Pyinstaller myself. I can tell you that the reason you're getting the error above is because it's attempting to run python code which does not have the proper syntax for the Python 2.5 interpreter. I'm going to vote this up and hope someone else will post a more insightful answer.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, my best guess at this point is there is a bug with the program, like you indicated. Hopefully someone will post a workaround.